# hql left join query for choice element?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, xsd, hql

I'm having trouble executing an hql query for tree like structured schema. And the elements having choice tag.

here is part of the xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="School">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="teacher" type="tns:Teacher" />
            <xs:element name="student" type="tns:Student" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Teacher">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="salaries" type="tns:Salary" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Salary">
    <xs:attribute name="startTime" type="xs:long" />
    <xs:attribute name="endTime" type="xs:long" />
    <xs:attribute name="amount" type="xs:double" />
</xs:complexType>
```

and here is the query:

```
TypedQuery<Salary> query = em.createQuery("select sal from School  s " + 
                                                  "left join s.teacher tc "+
                                                "left join tc.salaries sal "                                                  
                                              + "where tc.name='John'", Salary.class);
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any exceptions? or what means `I'm having trouble executing an hql query`

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: salaries of: com.XXX.XXX.jaxb.XXX.Teacher=the exception